# Firefox mobile (android) and orientationchange

Tags: firefox, mobile, android-orientation, orientation-changes

The event is not working in firefox mobile for android.

How do I detect the orientation change after all?

Comment: How did you use it in your code?

Comment: window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handleOrientation, false);

Comment: Got error message or doesn't fire? Is the device has motion detector at all?

Comment: No error.Galaxy s 1. and firefox is the only browswer that has a problem with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox for Android does not support the orientationchange event but you can achieve the same result by using media query listeners.

```
var mqOrientation = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)");

// The Listener will fire whenever this either matches or ceases to match
mqOrientation.addListener(function() { self.handleViewportChange(); });
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how this works, do you have a sample of code with something like an alert or a console.log to check the orientation change, please?

Answer (score 0):

this works like a charm on ff for android

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  alert($( window ).height());
});
```